# Deixar a barra centralizada usando dragdealer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando essa biblioteca para criar barras que o usuário possa interagir: http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer.

Gostaria que a barra de arrastar começasse no 0, ou seja, no meio da barra:
[image: O que gostaria]

Porém, a tenho da seguinte forma:
[image: Situação real]

HTML:

```
<div id="just-a-slider4" class="dragdealer">
   <div style="text-align:center" class="handle red-bar">
      <span class="value"></span>%
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#just-a-slider {
   height: 60px;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
   align-content: center;
}
#just-a-slider .handle {
   height: 60px;
   line-height: 60px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background-color:#2c3e50;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
   new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
      animationCallback: function(x, y) {
         $('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x = 100-x*200));
         if (x <0 ) {
            $('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x = -x));;
         }
      }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar o método `setValue` para especificar o valor inicial desejado. Veja a função com algumas otimizações:

```
d = new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
    animationCallback: function(x, y) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerText = Math.abs( Math.floor(x*200-100) );
    }
});

// Aqui setamos o valor inicial:
d.setValue(0.5, 0, true);
```

Veja o demo no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/6r50a03u/)**.

**Notas:**

- No HTML acertei o `ID` do seu código, tinha um `4` sobrando no final do `just-a-slider`;
- troquei o class do `value` por ID, para facilitar o *update* do valor sem complicações;
- No *callback* eu eliminei a dependência do jQuery, para ficar um demo mais adequado para uso geral;
- A função `Math.abs` retorna o número sempre positivo, eliminando a necessidade do `if` que você utilizou no *Callback*. Que por sinal, tinha duas atribuições `x =` que eu imagino não serem necessárias.

Segue o HTML atualizado:

```
<div id="just-a-slider">
   <div class="handle" style="text-align:center">
      <span id="value">0</span>%
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.